# Dart console app with cloud firestore and firebase storage

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to make a Dart console app that interact with cloud firestore and firebase storage.

My first question is: is that possible?

I searched the web for hours looking for examples but i didn't find any. all i found is this [example here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase#-readme-tab-), but i didn't understand how this work. I tried this code :

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart' as fs;

void main() {
  initializeApp(
    apiKey: "YourApiKey",
    authDomain: "YourAuthDomain",
    databaseURL: "YourDatabaseUrl",
    projectId: "YourProjectId",
    appId: "YourAppId",
    storageBucket: "YourStorageBucket");

  fs.Firestore store = firestore();
  fs.CollectionReference ref = store.collection('myCollection');
  ref.onSnapshot.listen((querySnapshot) {
    print(querySnapshot);
  });  
}
```

The first thing is i don't know where i can find those `initializeApp` info like `YourApiKey`, `YourAuthDomain` ...

The second thing is VS code is giving me this warning

```
Omit type annotations for local variables.
```

Answer (score -2):

First thing: from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/), open your Firebase project. [I assume you already have one?]

Click on "+Add App" and select "Web" as the platform.

Enter a nickname for the app and click on "Register app"

It will then generate the values for you. Copy them, and paste them somewhere safe and click "Continue to the console".

Then you can copy and paste the various values into your code as appropriate.

Second thing: you can ignore those to begin with. They're a matter of style and they won't stop your code compiling or running.